# How to analyse an NER that is trained using Spacy?

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

This is a simple code that is picked up from the tutorial documentation (more or less). Once I train the NER model using the below training code, I use `nlp(sentence).ents` inside the for loop to get the named entities. As you can see, I used a blank model `spacy.blank('en')` this was because I am adding new entities. But no entities are detected from the test set.

```
import spacy
import random
from spacy.util import compounding
from spacy.util import minibatch
def get_batches(train_data, model_type):
    max_batch_sizes = {'tagger': 32, 'parser': 16, 'ner': 16, 'textcat': 64}
    max_batch_size = max_batch_sizes[model_type]
    if len(train_data) < 1000:
        max_batch_size /= 2
    if len(train_data) < 500:
        max_batch_size /= 2
    batch_size = compounding(1, max_batch_size, 1.001)
    batches = minibatch(train_data, size=batch_size)
    return batches

nlp = spacy.blank('en')
nlp.vocab.vectors.name = 'blank_vector'
optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
for i in range(20):
    random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
    batches = get_batches(TRAIN_DATA, 'ner')
    for batch in batches:
        texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
        nlp.update(texts, annotations, drop=0.5, sgd=optimizer)
#     for text, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
#         nlp.update([text], [annotations], drop=0.5, sgd=optimizer)
nlp.to_disk('model')
```

***How does one go about analysing a model created in spacy?*** I did try to understand some of it by looking at the `model` that was created by `nlp.to_disk('model')`. But unfortunately I did not know how to add the necessary information that I need.

**My Requirement:** Consider percentages like [20%, 0.5% etc] and dollar amounts like [$100, 100 dollars etc] such occurences will be picked up as *MONEY, PERCENT* by the pre-trained NER but I need them to detect entities based on usage such as ['HOME_LOAN_INTEREST_RATE', 'CAR_LOAN_INTEREST_RATE' etc]. Now my problem could still be because all the dollar amounts are not present in the vocabulary. If that is the case, how do I go about fixing this problem.

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hey , i can help you but can you be more clear on this " I need them to detect entities based on usage such as ['HOME_LOAN_INTEREST_RATE', 'CAR_LOAN_INTEREST_RATE' etc]."

Comment: Hey Gideon, Those were just new entities. I have figured out what was wrong with the code. I needed to create a pipe for ner and I was not doing that in the code above. Also, there is a losses parameter in the update function that can be used for finding out about the progress of the model. I still have not figured out the loss functions that are used but hey.. it works once we add the pipes to the code

Answer (score 1):

The `update` function has a `losses` parameter which can be used to find out the loss of the model in each iteration.

Also, the reason my NER model did not find the tags that I had in my dataset was that NER operation was (possibly) not performed at all as I did not find the ner folder inside the created model. To fix this, we have to create something called pipes.

```
if "ner" not in nlp.pipe_names:
    ner = nlp.create_pipe("ner")
    nlp.add_pipe(ner, last=True)
# otherwise, get it so we can add labels
else:
    ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")

# add labels
for _, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
    for ent in annotations.get("entities"):
        ner.add_label(ent[2])

# get names of other pipes to disable them during training
other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != "ner"]
```

I am sure someone else can better explain ways to analyse the performance of the model but this is what I did to fix my problem.

```
with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):
    nlp.vocab.vectors.name = 'blank_vector'
    optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
    for i in range(10):
        random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
        losses = {}
        batches = get_batches(TRAIN_DATA, 'ner')
        for batch in batches:
            texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
            nlp.update(texts, annotations, losses=losses, drop=0.1, sgd=optimizer)
            print('Losses:', losses)
nlp.to_disk('model')
```

Will be reading more on the documentation to find out about the optimizers and the loss functions. But feel free to add another answer / edit this to provide better explanation.